# fork() sequence of execution?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel

```
int main () { 

    fork ();     
    fork ();     
    fork (); 

    pf (" hi\n"); 

}
```

How many times the "hi" will print?
What is sequence of execution for fork() ?
os:linux compiler:gcc

Comment: `fork` can fail, so you cannot be sure of the answer. Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) which has several chapters explaining that.

Comment: Answer will not be constant.

Comment: And by definition `fork` is observably *not* sequential (but usually parallel, it returns twice).

Comment: If every fork goes fine, it'll be 8.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26716300/2411320

Comment: It is very low quality. A simple search would result answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1: How many times the "hi" will print?**

```
                      Due to first Fork
                             |
                   -------------------------
                   |                        |
             Due to second fork         Due to second fork
                   |                          |
          ----------------------            ----------------------------
        |                      |            |                          |
  Due to 3rd fork        Due to 3rd fork   Due to 3rd fork             Due to 3rd fork
        |                      |                |                           |
------------------       ---------------       ----------               ------------
|               |        |             |      |          |               |          |
process-1     process-2   process-3   process-4 pr-5     pr-6         process-7    process-8
```

So 
if all `fork` goes well then total 8 process created so there will be 8 or lesser hi will be there in output

**Question 2: What is sequence of execution for fork() ? os:linux compiler:gcc**

There is no any guarantee which process will be scheduled first and which one second. 
Its all depends on Scheduler.