# Mechanics of multiple inheritance compared to templates wrt building flexible designs

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance, policy-based-design

This is a narrower version of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549573/understanding-the-exposition-of-alexandrescu-about-the-weaknesses-of-multiple-in) put on hold due to being too broad.

On pages 6-7 of **Modern C++ Design**, Andrei Alexandrescu lists three ways in which the *multiple inheritance* is weaker than *templates* with respect to building flexible designs. In particular, he states that the *mechanics* provided by *multiple inheritance* is poor (the text in square brackets and formatting are mine as per *my* understanding of the context):

> In such a setting [i.e. *multiple inheritance*], [to build a flexible `SmartPtr`,] the user would build a multithreaded, reference-counted smart pointer class by inheriting some `BaseSmartPtr` class and two classes: `MultiThreaded` and `RefCounted`. Any experienced class designer knows
>   that such a naïve design does not work.
>
> ...
>
> 1. *Mechanics.* There is no boilerplate code to assemble the inherited components in a controlled
>      manner. The only tool that combines BaseSmartPtr, MultiThreaded, and RefCounted
>      is a language mechanism called multiple inheritance. The language applies
>      simple superposition in combining the base classes and establishes a set of simple rules
>      for accessing their members. This is unacceptable except for the simplest cases. Most
>      of the time, you need to **orchestrate** the workings of the inherited classes carefully to
>      obtain the desired behavior.

When using *multiple inheritance*, one can achieve some pretty flexible orchestration by writing member functions that call member functions of several base classes. So, what is the orchestration that is missing from *multiple inheritance* and present in templates?

Please note that not every disadvantage of *multiple inheritance* compared to *templates* goes as an answer here, but only a disadvantage in what Andei calls *mechanics* in the above quote. In particular, please make sure that you are not talking about one of the other two weaknesses of *multiple inheritance* listed by Andrei:

> 2. *Type information*. The base classes do not have enough type information to carry on
>      their tasks. For example, imagine you try to implement deep copy for your smart
>      pointer class by deriving from a DeepCopy base class. But what interface would DeepCopy
>      have? It must create objects of a type it doesn’t know yet.
> 3. *State manipulation*. Various behavioral aspects implemented with base classes must manipulate
>      the same state. This means that they must use virtual inheritance to inherit a
>      base class that holds the state. This complicates the design and makes it more rigid because
>      the premise was that user classes inherit library classes, not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what Alexandrescu is referring to in the "Mechanics" paragraph is expounded upon in the rest of the chapter. He's referring to how much more flexible policy-based class design is than inheritance-based class design, particularly with respect to the various ways in which policies can be implemented and combined - this in comparison to the single implementation and combination allowed through multiple inheritance.

For instance, when discussing the `Creator` policy he points out that the policy requires only a Create() method that returns a pointer to the class being created, but doesn't specify that it be virtual or non-static. And he shows several ways in which each policy could be created: a straightforward policy class such as (from section 1.5, skipping the MallocCreator and PrototypeCreator policies)

> ```
> template<class T>
> struct OpNewCreator
> {
>   static T* Create()
>   {
>     return new T;
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> ...

```
>     //Library code
>     template <class CreationPolicy>
>     class WidgetManager:public CreationPolicy
>     {
>     ...
>     };
```

> ...
>
> ```
> // Application Code
> typedef WidgetManager<OpNewCreator<Widget> > MyWidgetMgr;
> ```

or it could be implemented with template template parameters (section 1.5.1) as

> ```
> //Library Code
> template <template <class> class Creation Policy>
> class WidgetManager : public CreationPolicy <Widget>
> {
> ...
> }
>
> // Application Code
> typedef WidgetManager<OpNewCreator> MyWidgetMgr
> ```

or (section 1.5.2) - implemented as a template member function:

> ```
> struct OpNewCreator
> {
>   template <class T>
>   static T* Create()
>   {
>     return new T;
>   }
> ```

}

These are examples of the flexible mechanics that are available in a template-based policy class solution and not available in a multiple inheritance solution. These particular examples are not maybe all that exciting, probably because they have to be short and simple for pedagogical reasons.