# Arrangement of 2 by 2 condition in if statement in C-family language

Tags: c++, c

When programming, I'm usually dealing with two sets of conditions combined together, like:

```
if (A && B){...}
else if (!A && B){...}
else if (A && !B){...}
else if (!A && !B){...}
```

It can also be resolved using nested if statements.

```
if (A){
    if (B) {...}
    else {...}
}
else {
    if (B) {...}
    else {...}
}
```

**EDIT:** Some new thoughts, what about I firstly evaluate both A and B and store as temporary variable (then do as the first approach) in case that the evaluation of A and B both have no side-effect?

---

So my question is there any performance difference between them and what about their readability?

*I code in C++, if matters.*

Comment: A decent compiler would give you the same object code for this. Good to the check the assembly code generated in this case

Comment: Please Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532160/does-short-circuiting-make-execution-of-the-program-faster-and-is-analysing-whi

Comment: about readability, I would say the 1st version is clearer

Comment: You can guess at it, but you can't be *sure* unless you try it both ways and check the performance of your program.

Comment: @sjsam, is that what g++'s `-fif-conversion` do? The document is not clear about it.

Comment: It may depend on the statistical distribution of A and B.  If both are more likely to be true, then you get 2 evaluations and one branch.  If both are likely to be false, then....you might consider re-ordering your expressions.  Though the compiler will decide, but the processor's branch prediction may be able to figure things out and preload instructions on the most likely code path and eliminate any advantages the that compiler might provide.  Code for clarity and intent before you optimize

Comment: @YiFei For the very basic applications of both the styles [\[ code1 \]](http://pastebin.com/raw/QUyimUtE) & [\[ code 2\]](http://pastebin.com/raw/MJMqY4x2)  when compiled with `g++ -O2 -S -masm=intel -fif-conversion` gave me the same [\[ assembly \]](http://pastebin.com/VHcUmjF9)except for the change in filename

Comment: @YiFei : And the g++ manpage is pretty clear about `-fif-conversion`  which says  `-fif-conversion
           Attempt to transform conditional jumps into branch-less
           equivalents.  This includes use of conditional moves, min, max, set
           flags and abs instructions, and some tricks DOABLE by standard
           arithmetics.` Also the `doable` may be a hint that this may not work for complex cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two cases are not the same. In the second case, `A` and `B` will each be evaluated exactly once. In the first case, `A` and `B` will evaluated a number of times, depending upon their value.

While this almost certainly won't affect the optimization of the typical case, it will matter if `A` or `B` have side effects.

Comment: Question is Similar: : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532160/does-short-circuiting-make-execution-of-the-program-faster-and-is-analysing-whi

Comment: Yes, that is similar to OP's performance question, but not his readability question. But bear in mind that my answer only addresses his unasked question: "are they semantically equivalent?"

Comment: Why wouldn't the compiler generate some code that use the previously evaluated value?

Comment: @Robᵩ, yes I agree with your answer!

Comment: Wouldn't B evaluated twice?

Comment: @YiFei, to some extent some of these condition statements can be solved by branch prediction. To boost performance.

Comment: @YiFei - Because the language doesn't allow it. Suppose your `A`, for example, is a function call. The compiler must invoke the function each time it is listed, potentially with side effects. OTOH, if `A` has no visible side effects, then the compiler can optimize both cases to the same code.

Comment: @noob - No, `B` is evaluated only once. It might be evaluated in the `A == true` branch, or it might be evaluated in the `A == false` branch, but either way exactly once.

Comment: @noob, how can B be evaluated twice? It only enters the first statement if A is true,

Comment: Aha, then doesn't the second approach potentially more optimiz-able?

Comment: @YiFei, No it is not, it is only optimizable if you guessed correctly that the first statement has a higher chance of failing since it is an &&, and in this case it would completely skip the inside of the if statement, if you guessed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to predict which code generation strategy the compiler will choose in cases like that (and it can actually depend on surrounding context). This makes your question unanswerable in general case. One should normally expect the compiler to be smart enough to recognize the equivalence of both of your constructs (assuming they are indeed equivalent) and choose the most optimal one automatically.

The most optimal code generation strategy might be something else altogether, e.g.

```
// Assuming A and B are either 0 or 1 
switch ((A * 2) + B) {
  case 0: ...; break;
  case 1: ...; break;
  case 2: ...; break;
  case 3: ...; break;
}
```

Just choose whatever makes your code more readable.

Comment: Just a thought: use bit shift instead of multiplying seems better :)

Comment: @YiFei: Bit shift is not better in this context.

Comment: Then yes because of the plus sign.

Comment: `switch(bool(A)*2 + bool(B)) {` makes the assumption unnecessary. Or, to us an idiom that predates the `bool` type: `switch ( (!!A)*2 + (!!B) ) {`.

Comment: @YiFei I totally agree! `(A << 1) | B` looks so much more beautify!

Comment: @Robᵩ: The point was not to dive into the domain of compiler optimizations too deeply. If the compiler wanted to go in that direction it would implement the normalization as `!A*2 + !B` (there's no real need for double negation), but for a human this just makes things progressively more and more difficult to read. I didn't want to go too far in that direction, since it wasn't the main point of my answer.

Comment: Actually, it's better to leave this transform to the compiler. The reason is hidden in the `...`. Those cases might be folded, but the folding might only be possible if the compiler used e.g. `switch (A*3+B) { case 4: ...`

Answer (score 0):

It's a hard question; honestly, I think everyone looks at this a little bit differently.  As people have mentioned here it does not matter as a compiler should generate the same output for both **(should! not necessarily will — it honestly depends on the code)**.

Yet, for example, let's look at this code:

```
int  Nested(int a)
{       
    if(a > 0)
    {
        if( a > 1)
        {
            if( a % 2 == 0)
            {
                if( a % 10 == 4)
                {
                    printf("a is valid");
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {               
                    printf("a's last digit inst 4");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" a is not odd");
            }    
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" a is not bigger than 1");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" a is not bigger than 0");
    }

    return 0;

}

int NotNested(int a)
{
    if(a <= 0)
    {
        printf(" a is not bigger than 0");
        return 0;
    }

    if(a <= 1)
    {
        printf(" a is not bigger than 1");
        return 0;
    }

    if(a % 2 != 0)
    {
        printf(" a is not odd");
        return 0;
    }

    if( a % 10 != 4)
    {
        printf("a's last digit inst 4");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("a is valid");

    return 1;

}
```

I personally think that `NotNested` in my example is much more readable,
yet it's my personal opinion and both of these functions should do the same.

**So yeah, in terms, of readability try to avoid nesting.**