# Can I get a warning always evaluates to true in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, warnings

I had in my code a bug like this:

```
if 'char' or 'CHAR' in dt:
    foo = 'ch'
```

and it took me a while to debug it. If I am correct, the first operand always evaluates to true, which causes the body of the if statement to always execute.

In C++ I would get a warning in some of these cases, making the annihilation of such bugs easy.

Is there any way that I can get Python warn me about these situations, or not (because it gets interpreted or something)?

Comment: It's a string @raj, updated. It should be the data types, but you know users . . .

Comment: Get a warning from who? The python interpreter? Your python IDE? A tool made specifically to detect this kind of thing?

Comment: Static analysis tools might be able to figure these out, but the error is very obvious.

Comment: @Jean PyCharm does not seem to catch this particular problem.

Comment: It was me in the past @Jean-FrançoisFabre. I should tell myself something! Pycharm might be a good solution, if it really does the trick, Aran-Fey for example. Matthiueu, sorry.... Jean-Francois, maybe post an answer?

Comment: @raj It's pretty irrelevant what `dt` is, the error is (somewhat) obvious either way.

Comment: @deceze in large code files, even the simplest of things can be hard to get traced some times. Machines can help fight my human nature. =)

Comment: FWIW, `'char' or anything` evaluates to `'char'` since a non-empty string is True-ish, and `anything` isn't evaluated (eg if it's a function it's not called), since `or` short-circuits.

Comment: @PM2Ring correct, thanks. But even if it didn't short-circuit, it would still behave the same. We have this [mechanism in C as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716255/why-does-this-program-print-forked-4-times/26716300#26716300), but that's beside the point.

Comment: @PM2Ring I think he knows. It's just a typo, but once it's coded & lost in the code, it's hard to debug

Comment: So anyone can tell op use which tool can get a warning, `pylint` or `flake8`? Seems all cannot show a warning.

Comment: @lagom to relax a bit the question, anything would do, from a warning, to an error. I just would like a sign... =) PS: A negative answer would also be appreciated, since it would make me stop searching. I would love to get feedback from the downvoter, and then improve the question, or even delete it, if needed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sure, I was just elaborating because "the first operand always evaluates to true" doesn't quite explain what's going on.

Comment: @gsamaras Understood. FWIW, I learned C a few decades before I learned Python. I agree that it is a tricky thing to debug, but as with any language, you gradually learn to look for "likely suspects" like this. I think it would be tricky for an automatic tool to find this sort of thing and not get too many false positives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult not to emit false positives in the general case. Imagine this code:

```
if list_empty or x in my_list:
```

this is perfectly valid to any human because `list_empty` is probably a boolean. Now with:

```
if number1 or number2 in my_list:
```

A (woken up :)) human sees the error immediately (because the names are similar, and usually identify numbers not conditions, same for strings with `if name1 or name2 in my_list:`), but that would require the static analyser to *know* the type for sure.

And even in those "trivial" cases, who knows if the programmer didn't want to test if `number1` is zero or `name1` is empty to proceed to the next test?

Type annotations may help, I didn't test all tools out there to give you a positive answer but the dynamic nature of python makes it very difficult to be sure of the intent of the programmer, and what's worth an analyser program with emits a ton of false positives?

For string & integer/float literals this construct is probably a mistake, so I wrote a lousy static analyzer with regexes. Cheap and if it yells, you're very likely with a faulty line (standalone example here which self-analyses itself):

```
dt=[]
if 'char' or 'CHAR' in dt:
    foo = 'ch'
if 12.0 and 45 in dt:
    foo = 'ch'

import re
infamous_bug = re.compile("if\s+(['\"].*?['\"]|[\d\.]+)\s+(or|and)")
with open(__file__) as f:
    for line in f:
        if infamous_bug.search(line):
            print("GOTCHA {}".format(line.rstrip()))
```

outputs:

```
GOTCHA if 'char' or 'CHAR' in dt:
GOTCHA if 12.0 and 45 in dt:
```

Comment: What exactly is the obvious error in `number1 or number2 in my_list`…?

Comment: the correlation between the names help the human reader to see that the intent is to test if both numbers belong to `my_list` that's what I meant.

Comment: Mmm, the human author could also plausibly mean "number1 is non-zero or number2 is in list"…

Comment: true that's why it's difficult to tell for sure.